# How do you add maps?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to add Asteroid 5251  I put the unzipped folder in my "saves" folder but when I open the game the only thing I see is my map.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Minecraft map won't show up when I open up the game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194621/my-minecraft-map-wont-show-up-when-i-open-up-the-game)

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your save is not nested inside some other folder. You should have it unzipped so that the `level.dat` file for Asteroid 5251 is at the following level:

```
.minecraft/saves/Asteroid5251/level.dat
```

Make sure it's not nested too deeply, e.g.

```
.minecraft/saves/Asteroid5251/saves/level.dat
```

Answer (score 3):

The Map folder is in fact nested in the zip file. In the zip there is a map folder. In the map folder are two folders "Asteroid 5251" and "Pipeworks Challenge". Those two folders go in the saves directory.