# My Minecraft map won't show up when I open up the game

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently downloaded a map labeled "Laidback Parkour". When I tried opening it up on the launcher, it didn't show up, but it is definitely in the "saves" folder. Can someone tell me what's going on and help me fix this? I have followed the steps on the Wiki page, but I still don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Which version of Minecraft was the map created with? And does it require any mods?

Comment: 1.7 and no, it does not require any mods.

Comment: Related: [Where did the world go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/32254/185203), if the map previously worked but disappeared during a crash.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure it's because you have the map folder inside another folder.

Try dragging the Equesrtia4 into the saves, rather than the Equestria. I've had issues like this with maps as well, and doing that helped me get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't launch games through the Minecraft launcher. You launch it through the singleplayer button inside the Main Menu. You launch a 1.7 client game through the launcher but not a save..

Go to Singleplayer and your map should be located there.

Comment: some people....

Comment: Actually, I did check my single player multiple times. I also checked saves and it seems that it's not showing up, no matter what I do...

Comment: Is it a zip file or a folder. It must be a folder.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the "level.dat" file may have become corrupted.

Go into the folder of the save that you want to "recover".
Back up both 'level.dat' and 'level.dat_old'. Then, delete the original level.dat file and rename 'level.dat_old' to 'level.dat'.

If this works, you may or may not have lost some amount of progress, but the save file will show up in the world select screen and be accessible.

([Source](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/archive/legacy-support/1734569-save-is-in-minecraft-but-not-showing-up-in-game))

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem happen to me when i was trying to play on a MEGA CUBE survival map i downloaded. My problem was when I tried to rename the file to "world 1" it ended up just creating another file in-between the saves - MEGA CUBE folders, called "world 1."

I Had To:

- Open .minecraft, Saves folder, then my "fake world 1" folder.
- Drag the map folder to desktop.
- Click back button on folder TO Saves and delete my "Fake World 1" folder.
- Drag the map folder from desktop to Saves.
- Reload Minecraft

Before trying this, double check and make sure your file is "unzipped." And that your putting the downloaded map in the right folder.

I hope this helped!