# Why can't I open my Minecraft map even though it exists in the Minecraft saves folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been trying to download an Equestria map (from My Little Pony). I have extracted and unzipped it, but when I open the Minecraft launcher and click single player I can never find the map that I downloaded. How can I fix this??

This is the map I've been trying to download:
http://www.minecraftworldmap.com/worlds/B0Py8/full

Please have a look at the link and tell me how I can fix this!

Here is a screenshot of what's in the map folder. You can see up the top that it's in my saves folder. Am I missing anything?

[image: Here is a screenshot of what's in the map folder. You can see up the top that it's in my saves folder. Am I missing anything?]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Minecraft map won't show up when I open up the game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194621/my-minecraft-map-wont-show-up-when-i-open-up-the-game)