# Can't find my maps in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I downloaded a map and extracted the `.zip`, then I went into the MC launcher, went to edit profile, clicked on open game dir, went into my saves folder, then I transferred my map to that folder, reloaded Minecraft, went into the singleplayer menu, and now I can't find the map. Not only that, but the maps that I created are gone as well!

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that the map is for the same version of MC that you're running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I open my Minecraft map even though it exists in the Minecraft saves folder?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/208330/why-cant-i-open-my-minecraft-map-even-though-it-exists-in-the-minecraft-saves-f)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [My Minecraft map won't show up when I open up the game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194621/my-minecraft-map-wont-show-up-when-i-open-up-the-game)

Answer (score 1):

> clicked on open game dir, went into my saves folder, then I transferred my map to that folder

That is the right way, but make sure what you are dragging in is a folder with files like `level.dat` inside directly, not something like `dir/to/Map/` which has a folder in it like `Parkour`, which is the actual map. If there is a `level.dat` directly in the folder you dragged in to your `saves` folder, you should be good.

> Not only that, but the maps that I created are gone as well!

Without more information, all I can suggest is,

1. Under `Edit Profile` in the Minecraft launcher, is the box that says `Game Directory` unchecked? (Or, is it correct if you actually use this feature?)
2. Is anything under `saves` in the `.minecraft`(or `minecraft` on a Mac) folder? Access it using the `Open Game Dir` button, or go to the search bar and type `%appdata%` and find `.minecraft` on Windows, or go to `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/` on a Mac. If not, you likely can't get them back without a backup.

Answer (score 0):

1. Search .minecraft in your folders.
2. Click on it.
3. Go into the maps folder.
4. Drag the map in.

I am not sure if extracting it does something. I always just dragged it in and it worked fine.

Comment: He says he has already put the map into his saves folder.

Answer (score 0):

Do this from top to bottom

WinKey + R

Then type: %appdata%

Dubble click on your .minecraft folder

There must be a saves folder

Copy and paste your map to there

Reload your minecraft

Go to singleplayer and there it is

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before, too. I know how to fix it.
But, what is your game directory? If `C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions`, this directory is wrong. Change to this. `C:\User\YourUsername\Appdata\Roaming\.minecraft` But the quicker way is to uncheck Game Directory.

> I can't find the map. Not only that, but the maps that I created are gone as well!

You were loading Minecraft without the saved worlds even multiplayer servers. It's because it directed to your Minecraft Versions. And, it is not loading your worlds.