# Why doesn't a downloaded map show up in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have downloaded a map recently, I did all the steps, but it won't show up in the single player section. I double checked everything, also the resources packs.

Comment: this might be related http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259141/cant-find-my-maps-in-minecraft

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Minecraft map won't show up when I open up the game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194621/my-minecraft-map-wont-show-up-when-i-open-up-the-game)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the map you've downloaded doesn't appear in your Singleplayer section?

If so, then double check if it's in the right directory. `%appdata%/.minecraft/saves`

If it is, then there might be a common issue that the actual map is inside the folder you've dragged. (Just check the folder that you've dragged, it should look something like this:

[image: Folder Example]

Answer (score 2):

> I did all the steps, but it won't show up in the single player section. I double checked everything, also the resources packs.

Your map is `.rar` and must be extracted. When extracted, all of these kind of files in a folder must be required:

[image]

There should be a `level.dat` file. Which is important. Cut the foder and paste it to the saves folder. Be noticed that your map doesn't shows at the top of your singleplayer section, so find the map and play it.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is way way more simple. Copy every folder in the map folder and paste it in a new, ungenerated world and have fun with your skyblock map in another, unexpected world.

Answer (score -3):

Is this doesn't work, rename the `level.dat` file like how I did.

If it says `level.dat_old` but and delete the other `level.dat` file, but if  there are other `level.dat` files like `_mcr`, don't delete them, but delete them if it still doesn't work!

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit? If what doesn't work?