# My map won't show up after I've put it in the saves folder

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently downloaded the map "Fun Time Theme Park," and when I opened my launcher it didn't show up. It is definitely in the saves folder. I'm on a mac, by the way. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Did you extract it from the .zip or .rar? It doesn't work with compressed folders

Comment: Did you make sure you didn't accidently put it in a folder in a folder? The map will only be seen by minecraft if the folder directly has the `level.dat` file in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I open my Minecraft map even though it exists in the Minecraft saves folder?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/208330/why-cant-i-open-my-minecraft-map-even-though-it-exists-in-the-minecraft-saves-f)

Answer (score 1):

You might be on the wrong Minecraft version. Try checking the page that you downloaded the map on, and see if it has any information on what version it has to be on.

If this does not work then try looking into the file, some maps i have downloaded have a file with the map name and then inside that file they have the map itself. I hope this helps.