# Why are my Minecraft maps not showing up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm having problems with getting Minecraft maps. Some of them work, but others don't. I'm trying to get the "Titanic Survival 2" map but it just won't show up.

I'm doing everything correctly: downloading the file, extracting the `.zip`, and putting it into my `saves` folder. But whenever I launch Minecraft and look in my singleplayer worlds, it's not there. I've tried downloading it from different sites, opening it with different installations, and more, but nothing is working. I'm confused because some maps work but others do not.

Comment: We'll need more info, including your folder structure and what is inside the folders. Ensure that inside the folder that is inside `saves`, there is all the world data with `data`, `datapacks` and other folders, ensure there aren't other folders like "The Map" enclosing them

Comment: All of my other maps (including the ones that work) are in the same saves folder. I've checked multiple times, and the map I want is in there with all the data and stuff.

Comment: When I had this problem it was because I happened to have "two copies" of Minecraft and thus saves were in some other what-not directory. Can you make a new world, save it and check if it's there? If not then select it in the game menu, click "edit", press "open world folder" and it will show you the directory for that file.  You can then try to move files there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I open my Minecraft map even though it exists in the Minecraft saves folder?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/208330/why-cant-i-open-my-minecraft-map-even-though-it-exists-in-the-minecraft-saves-f)

Answer (score -1):

Open the .zip File
Probebly there is another folder in that,
I had The same problem and did this,
Then extract the folder to saves.

Comment: This answer is slightly vague. Could you give more detail please, as it helps future readers a ton?