# I have been trying to download a Minecraft map but it never shows in single player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've followed step-by-step articles telling me what to do.
I've unzipped the folder, opened my ".minecraft" folder, looked for saves and pasted it in there. And then all they say is that if I run my launcher it should show in my Minecraft single player saved worlds but it never does.

I've checked that it's the same version and I've double checked that it is in the same folder and is unzipped, but still it doesn't show up. What do I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Go into the extracted folder. Is there a file called "level" or "level.dat", or do you need to go into another folder first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I open my Minecraft map even though it exists in the Minecraft saves folder?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/208330/why-cant-i-open-my-minecraft-map-even-though-it-exists-in-the-minecraft-saves-f)

Answer (score -1):

totally super easy simple steps if doesn't work idk why:

step 1: download world (example here being `world.zip`)

step 2: unzip `world.zip` **inside** `.minecraft\saves`

step 3: check inside zip file if there is another folder, drag the folder to the top level `saves` folder

step 4: check for `level.dat`

step 5: idk go into minecraft and check
btw don't forget to set your mc installation to the `.minecraft` that the `world.zip` is in

try to check now