# Custom map won't show in-game

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

I have been trying to download a Minecraft map, but it won't show in the game.
I have exported it, and it is in the `My Saves` folder, but I just can't find it in game. I'm in the version the map asked for, and I have tried what other people have said, such as "make sure its not within another folder", and "make sure there is a `level.dat`". I don't know if there should be more than one, since there are around eight of those: I don't know if that's the problem.
Nothing has worked so far, and I really want to play the map.

[Here](https://www.planetminecraft.com/project/the-biggest-and-most-realisitic-medieval-world/) is the map I'm trying to download, and here is the file in my saves folder:

[image: Screenshot of the /.minecraft/saves/ folder with the level.dat files]

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I don't know if this adds anything but I recently found 2 folders in my saves folder called "Falcon's rock v2.0.0 - Shortcut" and "Falcon's rock v2.0.0 - Shortcut (2)"

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure it's not in the list? It's an old world, so it appears at the bottom of the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Minecraft map won't show up when I open up the game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194621/my-minecraft-map-wont-show-up-when-i-open-up-the-game)